# Change element's css while its in visible zone

Tags: jquery, hover, focus

I have 4 blocks that have hover effect on desktop. But they should change their css when it's in visible zone themselves (in focus) on mobile. How can i do it? Help please, cannot find the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Check if element is visible after scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)